# How should I go about coding this password Manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and have recently been trying to learn/understand OOP. I decided to do a password manager as a project to help me learn as I have already done it using FP. However, I have gotten a tad lost in what I am doing and would greatly appreciate some help. I am lost in the creation of a user account and making an object out of it. And then use this in a login function to access the users password collection and make new passwords or edit existing ones if the credentials of the account match those in a dictionary of users. But i don't know how to do this honestly.

Any comments regarding my code style, like its readability and if it follows convention would also be of help.

```
`import random
import string
import secrets

class User():
    def __init__(self, username, credentials, password_dict) -> None:
        self.credentials = {}
        self.password_dict = {}
        
    def passGen(self, passDicts):
        n = int(input('Define password length. Longer passwords are safer.'))
        source = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        password = ''.join((random.choice(source) for i in range(n)))
        print('Password has been generated!')
        print('Would you like to save this password? Type y or n: ')
        yon = input()
        if yon == 'y':
            site = input('Please enter the site password is to be used:')
            self.password_dict[site] = password
        if yon == 'n':
            print('Okay')
            main()
        return self.password_dict
    #^Generates a new password for a given site and saves it to the users password (dictionary) collection
    def Credentials(self, credentials):
        username = str(input('Enter username: '))
        password = str(input('Enter password for your account'))
        if username in credentials:
            print('')    
        self.credentials[username] = password
       
def main():
    choice = input()
    if choice == '1':
        login()
    if choice == '2':
    `
```

#^^^
main() above is to display the menu and take the user to their saved passwords. Choice 1 is
login and choice 2 is exit. This will take the user to a menu where the can check passwords, download password dictionary as a text file, or edit existing passwords for a specified site.

Comment: FYI you should use `secrets.choice` not `random.choice` to generate the password

Comment: Can you ask one specific focused question and mention what exactly you are stuck on? "_I am lost in the creation of a user account and making an object out of it_" isn't really specific.

Comment: Also a common design choice would be to separate the password management class from the UI (i.e. printing messages to and from the console)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Apologies if my question is unclear. I wanted to ask how to have multiple users as objects/create a new user as an object (with credentials and a password collection), and then save each object in a dictionary or something so that I could have a login feature. Hopefully that clears things up :)

Comment: @edwardiano again you are giving a list of steps you want to perform. The key to asking a good question is to ask a _specific_ one, you've broken your problem down into various steps, great! Why then are you still trying to solve all steps in one go? Solve each step one by one, ask about the **specific step** you are stuck on. Also the best way to clarify anything about your question is to [edit] it.

Comment: @TomMcLean Yh I agree with you on the secrets. I was debating which would be better. But I think I originally used random.choice() because it worked. But when I used secrets it gave some sort of error. But I'll try it again.

Comment: @TomMcLean Thanks for your input as well. I didn't think of separating password management from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'd format it as following:

```py
import random
import string
import secrets

class User():
    def __init__(self, username, credentials, password_dict) -> None:
        self.credentials = {}
        self.password_dict = {}
        

    def Credentials(self, credentials): # save username and password
        username = str(input('Enter username: '))
        password = str(input('Enter password for your account'))

        if username in credentials:
            print('')    
        self.credentials[username] = password

    def passGen(self, passDicts): # random password generator
        n = int(input('Define password length. Longer passwords are safer.'))

        source = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        password = ''.join((random.choice(source) for i in range(n)))
        print('Password has been generated!')

        print('Would you like to save this password? Type y or n: ')
        yon = input()

        if yon == 'y':
            site = input('Please enter the site password is to be used:')
            self.password_dict[site] = password
        if yon == 'n':
            print('Okay')
            main()

        return self.password_dict
    
   
def main():
    choice = input()
    if choice == '1':
        login()
    if choice == '2':
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that is a much better way of structuring it.